# Can you use both Storyboard and Programmatic Code?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

I have a UILabel and a UITextfield and a UIButton
I set them in storyboard and constrained them to the SuperView

Later, I find out I need a UIScrollview to make sure the content is displayed properly

My Code looks like

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordConfirmTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *directionsLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;

@property UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property UIView *contentView;

@property UITapGestureRecognizer *tap;
@property CGSize kbSize;

@end

@implementation UserEditPasswordViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.directionsLabel.text = @"Enter in and confirm a new password. \n Leave blank for no changes";
    [self createScrollView];
    [self createContentView];
    [self addSubViews];
    [self customizeSaveButton];

}

#pragma mark - ScrollView

- (void)createScrollView
{
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - Create ContentView
- (void)createContentView
{
    self.contentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
}

#pragma mark - Add Subiews
- (void)addSubViews
{
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.saveButton];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.passwordTextField];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.passwordConfirmTextField];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.directionsLabel];
}

#pragma mark - Customize Save Button
- (void)customizeSaveButton
{
    self.saveButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.saveButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

#pragma mark - Tap Gesture
- (void)tapGestureRecognizerEndsEditing
{
    // tap gesture to dismiss the keybaord when user taps anywhere on screen

    self.tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                initWithTarget:self
                action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tap];
}



#pragma mark - Keyboard Notifications
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {

    // registers notifications for when the keyboard is shown and when the keyboard is hidden
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications {

    // deregisters the keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self tapGestureRecognizerEndsEditing];
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];

    self.kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, self.kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= self.kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.saveButton.frame.origin)) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.saveButton.frame.origin.y-self.kbSize.height);
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
    // function to dismiss the keyboard
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    [self.tap removeTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
}
```

But the scrollview is not working. The label, textfield, and button are showing just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Can you use a hybrid of storyboard AND programmatic code or is it one or the other?

Comment: try to set scrollview's content size programmatically

Comment: Swap two line  first : `self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];` and then ` self.scrollView.delegate = self;`

Comment: @kevin have you set scrollViewContent Size

Comment: If you need scrollView to avoid keyboard, easiest way - create TVC.

Comment: @AshokLondhe I've gone ahead and put in the contentsize. I've put the delegate in there as well. Still isn't working. Scrollview seems to be there, but the label, button, and textfield aren't scrolling

Comment: @ViralSavaj I've gone ahead and switched the delegate around, but still the scrollview isn't moving along with the items. The constraints to the superview seem to just keep it where its constained to

Comment: add contentView in ur ScrollView..

Comment: @KevinL. You need to Add Button ,Label and textFiled programmatically because you are creating contentView Programatically so you must crate All the controls Programmatically. Don't put all these controls directly on ScrollView

Comment: @AshokLondhe So the answer is if a scrollview is made programatically, the controls will have to be made programmatically as well? There's no way to create the UIViews and Controls on storyboard and add them to the scrollview as "addsubviews" ?

Comment: Yes there is the way.. You have to create the UIView(contentView in your case) from story board and add controls to that ZUIView. and Do add that UIView directly to story board. you can put it away..from scrollView and add that UIView to ScrollView programatically. it will definitely solve your problem and inform me after solving your problem.

Comment: @AshokLondhe I dragged a UIView to storyboard, dragged it as an IBOutlet and named it contentView. I constrained it to the content view, but sitll didn't show up. I think its one way or the other, probably just going to keep this simple view controller as a storyboard only view controller

Comment: @KevinL. This is so simple i am providing you one link just follow it.This link is for iPad design but you can do it for iPhone. ok.. http://www.teachersdoor.com/TipsNTricks/simplescroll.html

Answer (score 1):

Please set the delegate of scrollview.

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

I hope it's working for you.

Comment: @KevinL. yeah, but at the wrong place. What do you think `self.scrollView` is before you allocate it?

Comment: I put the delegate after the alloc init.
It's still not working the way that it should, as the keyboard is hiding the save button, which I have keyboard notifications to move the scrollview up. The scrollview seems to be present, just not moving up

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use both

first we have to create scrollview object, then add your views to the scrollview, Please check the below code, i tried it is working fine.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *helloWorldLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView addSubview:self.helloWorldLabel];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

if you want to scroll the scrollview, increase the scrollview content size like below

```
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(600, 2000);
```

Comment: Already alloc init:

self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

Comment: I added the UIViews already and constrained them to the superview, thats the only 3 objects on the storyboard. Scrollview and adding subviews was done programmatically.

Comment: okay, please provide code. And add background colour to the scrollview and check once

Comment: may i know the importance of content view here?

Comment: I've set the content size to be the width and frame of the view, but the IBOutlets are not moving along with the scrollview. They are added as a subviews to the contentview, which the contentview is added as a subview to the scrollview

Comment: @KevinL.if the scrollview content size is more than frame size then only it will scroll.